# Can't perambulate indexes in matrix the right way

Tags: c#, matrix

[image]

Hello. I have this task to sum the numbers as shown. Tried everything I can, but still not the right answer. Can I have some guidance?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        int n = (int)char.GetNumericValue(input[0]);
        int m = (int)char.GetNumericValue(input[2]);

        int[,] matrix = new int[n, m];

        int sum = 0;

        //fill matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = (j * 3 + 1) + i * 3;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; i+=1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) - i; j+=1)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sum += matrix[i, j + i] + matrix[i + 1, j + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would've a easier time hard coding the input (and naming them as "columns" and "rows" instead, much more readable).

What is the expected output? Not sure I'm following this sum. I'm guessing, 297? If so:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
                if(j == 5) Console.WriteLine();
                if (matrix[i, j] % 2 != 0)
        {
                    if (i == 0 || i == matrix.GetLength(0) - 1
                    || j == 0 || j == matrix.GetLength(0))
                {
                        sum += (matrix[i, j]);
                }
                    else
                {
                        sum += (matrix[i, j] * 2);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```